# Matrix & Playa calls slow my site down

Tags: expressionengine

I'm running a template with 1 channel to display about 500 entries.
These entries consist of a few textfields and a MX google maps field.

The page takes 4 seconds to load ( which is too long ) and when I look at the output profiler I notice a few hundred lines like this:

> (0.545310 / 45.39MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Matrix_ext/channel_entries_tagdata
>   (0.552964 / 45.42MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Playa_ext/channel_entries_tagdata
>   (0.553339 / 45.42MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Matrix_ext/channel_entries_tagdata
>   (0.561014 / 45.45MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Playa_ext/channel_entries_tagdata
>   (0.561453 / 45.45MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Matrix_ext/channel_entries_tagdata
>   (0.570236 / 45.49MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Playa_ext/channel_entries_tagdata
>   (0.570871 / 45.49MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Matrix_ext/channel_entries_tagdata
>   (0.581254 / 45.52MB) Calling Extension Class/Method: Playa_ext/channel_entries_tagdata
>   ...

Odd, since there are no playa or matrix fields in this channel.
I asked around on the P&T support forums, but maybe you guys are able to help ?

Comment: Are you able to share the template code?

Comment: template code doesn't really matter, it's just a channel with some fields. I already found the solution and posted it below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uninstalling the Matrix and Playa **Extensions** ( make sure you keep the field-types & module ) takes care of this.

The calls to Matrix & Playa are gone now, page loads fine. And everything else ( including Matrix & Playa fields ) still works.

Comment: So does this mean that playa & matrix extensions are useless? Sounds weird.

Comment: I think if you are using Matrix/Playa elsewhere you may run into issues. Typically if you find something that randomly isn't working with these add-ons, one of the first things support will have you check is whether the extension is enabled.

Comment: @pvledoux: Indeed, I wonder if I'm missing something crucial.

Comment: @JeremyGimbel I'm using Matrix & Playa everywhere else across the site and it all seems to work perfectly.

Comment: The Playa extension does a numbers of things, mainly enables some advanced parsing and rewriting module tags. Matrix does something similar. I am surprised they are working without it. These must be more advanced features.

Answer (score 6):

I think a good approach to this situation might be to use the Query Module. The Channel Entries tag returning that many results is going to be very heavy on queries. You can reduce the number significantly using the disable= parameter of the Channel Entries tag, disabling as much as possible, but sometimes it's much more efficient to just write a custom SQL query using the Query Module.

Comment: a bit unrelated to my question, but a good idea nevertheless. I'm going to give that one a shot.

Comment: Well sortof. Eliminating the CE tag will kill the extensions from running as well, since they're triggered by the tag.